# Classloading Confusion on Redeploying Application on WebLogic 12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, classloader, weblogic12c

I have an application which consists of an EJB module, a Web module, and a number of JARs (both my own and third party libs). It is packaged as an EAR file. The libs are in a directory "libs" and the EJB manifest file includes these in its classpath. The Web module is packaged without including dependencies or specifying classpath.

```
The EAR content (simplified):
/libs/model.jar
/libs/other.jar
ejb.jar
web.war
```

I have a @Stateless bean in my web module that looks up a bean from the EJB module by injection @EJB. Security is implemented by accessing and checking user role by a ThreadLocal on an ActiveUser class in model.jar. My @stateless web bean intializes some caches in a method annotated with @PostConstruct. In order to satisfy the Security module, it starts by setting system credentials on the ThreadLocal in ActiveUser. Then it calls a method on the injected EJB which returns data for the cache (after checking credentials on the ActiveUser)

When I deploy my application (using the weblogic maven plugin) everything works like a charm.

Then I redeploy my application (again using the weblogic maven plugin). I have read the WebLogic documentation and here it is stressed that on redeployment the old classloaders are discarded and new ones instantiated (as there is no way to unload or update classes loaded by a classloader). But my redeployment fails as the EJB complains that the user is not properly authenticated when the web module tries to read the data for the caches in the @PostConstruct.

After debugging the code, I found out that the Web module bean still uses the ActiveUser classdefinition loaded by the "old" classloader (the object ID is identical to that of the old classloader). The EJB bean uses the ActiveUser classdefinition loaded by the new classloader. So the ThreadLocals are of course not the same object any longer. I also imagine a number of ClassCastExceptions could be raised as a result of this particular state.

Why is this old "ghost" classloader still active? I inspected the classloader tree for my application using the WLS-cat application and only new classloaders are present here - there is no trace of the old classloader.

Any suggestions for course of action? Has anyone experienced this?

If I restart my managed server the application starts up without any problems but I don't feel like restarting after every redeployment: i want to redeploy nightly snapshot builds every night and run integration test automatically and the weblogic maven plugin does not have any goals for restarting servers.